# Using VIM keys in shell (zsh or bash)

Tags: vim, zsh

I want to use vim editing keys in my shell (zsh).

With `bindkey -v` i get VI keys, but i want visual and more advanced key shortcuts (like change inner word (`ciw`), which i use all the time)

btw, is superuser the right forum for this question?

Comment: Yes, Super User is a good place for this question.

Comment: // , Have you ever ended up getting the `~` key when you press `Delete`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for the `bash` part in the title: You can put `bash` into `vi` mode by calling `set -o vi` (e.g. put that into your `.bashrc`).
To bind functions to specific keys you have to use `bind` in `bash`. See `help bind` to list the available functions and examples of how to call it.

"Change inner word" is not in `vi`, but `vim`, so it is not available.

Comment: `set -o vi` doesn't work for me. I'm on CentOS 5.x.

Answer (score 3):

I know my answer is really late but if people are still searching for the same thing

For commands like `ciw` and commands from `surround.vim` use this zsh plugin
https://github.com/hchbaw/opp.zsh

For visual mode use this zsh plugin
http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~raybuntu/%2Bjunk/ZSH_stuff/annotate/head%3A/zle_vi_visual.zsh

Source them in your `.zshrc` to enable them

Answer (score 2):

In bash pressing `v` (in command mode) opens vi(m) with the current content of the command line. You can now edit the line, using every feature of vi(m), and after quitting the line will be automatically executed.

Take a look at [this article](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/bash-vi-editing-mode-cheat-sheet/) for a good introduction and a cheat sheet of vi command line editing mode.

Comment: Finally, a cheat sheet for this. Thanks. (after a decade)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that particular one, but these functions are documented in `man zshrle` and some of them may be unbound. Search that file for the string "vi-" to find the available vi functions.